# Not counting the time during the breaks in google gantt

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I want to use google gannt to present some data, here there is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pvskozw/3/)

Let suppose that the M01 has to work for 3 hours, it start at 10:00, it should stop at 12 for the break and start again at 14:00 and then work untill 15:00 pm.
how can I rappresent the break 12:00-14:00 in goggle gantt?
I tried to modify the options:

```
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
```

add the columns 2 times and then add 3 more field in :

```
['Research', 'M01', null,
     new Date(2015, 01, 05, 10, 00), new Date(2015, 01, 05, 12, 00), null,
     new Date(2015, 01, 05, 14, 00), new Date(2015, 01, 05, 15, 00), null,  
     100,  null],
```

but it doesn't work, there is a solution here or I should pick one another king of gantt?

Comment: google's gantt chart has limited functionality...

Comment: @WhiteHat, thankyou, do you know any gantt per web that does what i want to do?

Comment: check out the [Gantt Chart](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/?utm_expid=.t_GZsX2HQeaGs4tconytSg.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdhtmlx.com%2Fdocs%2Fproducts%2F) from DHX, the Standard edition is free under GNU GPL and works well...